# Want To find a particular number in a list , True/False. Loop isn't iterating. Can someone explain why

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

x = [1,9,9,9,9,2,3,4,5,6,7]

```
def consec_123(nums):
   for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
pass
```

#The result comes out as False, even though there is 2 on the list. A reply would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using? Please add the appropriate language tag to your question.

Comment: Delete the else. Add return False as last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have additional tab in else statement. In `consec_123` case the else is [else-if](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) statement, in `consec_Correct` the else is [for-else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) statement

```
x = [1,9,9,9,9,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def consec_Correct(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 2:
            return True
    else:
        return False
pass
print (consec_Correct(x))


def consec_123(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
pass
print (consec_123(x))
```

Print output :

```
True
False
```

You can see step by step what is happening [here](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=x%20%3D%20%5B1,9,9,9,9,2,3,4,5,6,7%5D%0Adef%20consec_Correct%28nums%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20range%280,%20len%28nums%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20nums%5Bi%5D%20%3D%3D%202%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20True%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20False%0Apass%0Aprint%20%28consec_Correct%28x%29%29%0A%0A%0Adef%20consec_123%28nums%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20range%280,%20len%28nums%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20nums%5Bi%5D%20%3D%3D%202%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20True%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20False%0Apass%0Aprint%20%28consec_123%28x%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)